# CSS selecting first within multiple elements of same name

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select only one `<a>` within some elements that have un-uinique classes. 
I cant figure out the right selector to use to get it right.

[Fiddle with my HTML and attempted selector](http://jsfiddle.net/5hjKP/)

Can this be done by only editing the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>` for imediate child select, and choose the first `<li>`, not the first `<a>`.

```
.menu-name-main-menu > ul > li:first-child > a {
background: red;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hjKP/1/

Answer (score 1):

It can.  Try this instead:

```
.menu-name-main-menu>ul>li:first-child>a {
    background: red;
}
```

So, this says, only select the direct child ul of the .menu-name-main-menu, then only its first child that is a direct child, then the anchor inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the selector:

**css**

```
div.menu-name-main-menu > ul.menu > li.menu__item > a:not(:only-child) {
    background: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hjKP/2/)

Comment: True, but he didn't said he will change his html :) I suggest a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, you can use "nth-of-type"
ex:

```
.menu-name-main-menu > ul a:nth-of-type(1){background:red;}
```